# Variable is display null value in Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber

I Have 3 classes in Java –

1)TestSetup (Baseclass) – I have defined two variable here and one method:

```java
public static Webdriver driver;
public String executionbrowsername;

        /**
         * Function which calls in BeforeTest Method (TestRunner.java)
         */
        public void beforeTest(ITestContext ctx, String browser) {          
    executionbrowsername =browser;
    }
```

2. TestRunner Class – This class extends TestSetup class.
   Here I have used below logic to get value of browser variable and call below method –

```java
      @Parameters("browser")
        @BeforeTest
        public void beforetest(ITestContext ctx, @Optional("firefox") String browser) { 
            bc.beforeTest(ctx,browser); 
            System.out.println("Execution Broswer in beforeTest - "+bc.executionbrowsername);
    }
```

3. Hooks class – This class extends TestSetup class and In this class I am using @Before annotation.

```java
    @Before
        public void beforeHooks(Scenario scenario) {
            System.out.println("Inside Beforehooks --- "+super.executionbrowsername);
            super.beforeMethod(scenario);       
        }
```

Issue – My Variable value of executionbrowsername becomes null here.

1. Is there any solution, so that it holds the same variable value in hooks class also?
2. Can we use hooks (@Before) in TestRunner class?
3. Can we Exetend Hooks Class in Test Runner Class?

I can not use variable as static here.

Comment: It is null because you never set it to anything else in the same object. Just use `super.beforetest` instead of `bc.beforetest`. non-static variables are only shared in the same object.

Comment: Hi dan1st, thanks for your response. In class 2 which is testrunner here I am able to print value in variable using bc.executionbrowsername. But in class 3 which is hook class I'm not able to print value of variable.

Comment: As I said, non-static variables are only shared in the same object.